# Slow MySQL query is filling up my disk space

Tags: mysql, database

this is the query I'm currently running (28 hours have passed!):

```
drop table if exists temp_codes;
create temporary table temp_codes
    select distinct CODE from Table1;
alter table temp_codes
    add primary key (CODE);

drop table if exists temp_ids;
create temporary table temp_ids
    select distinct ID from Table1;
alter table temp_ids
    add primary key (ID);

drop table if exists temp_ids_codes;
create temporary table temp_ids_codes
    select ID, CODE
    from temp_ids, temp_codes;

alter table temp_ids_codes
    add index idx_id(ID),
    add index idx_code(CODE); 

insert into Table2(ID,CODE,cnt)
select 
    a.ID, a.CODE, coalesce(count(t1.ID), 0)
from 
    temp_ids_codes as a
    left join Table1 as t1 on (a.ID = t1.ID and a.CODE=t1.CODE)
group by
    a.ID, a.CODE;
```

My table is this (Table1):

```
ID         CODE
-----------------
0001        345
0001        345
0001        120
0002        567
0002        034
0002        567
0003        567
0004        533
0004        008
......
(millions of rows)
```

And i'm running the above query in order to get this (Table2):

```
ID  CODE    CNT
1   008      0
1   034      0
1   120      1
1   345      2
1   533      0
1   567      0
2   008      0
2   034      1
...
```

CNT are the counts of each Code for each ID..
How can I implement this in the best way to improve performance and not use disk space?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you only have 6 codes?  I suspect the cross join is generating much more data than you think.

Comment: no, I have thousands of codes...This is just a sample

Comment: Start Query withe `LIMIT 1000` and see what is wrong with result

Comment: You actually showed several successive queries. Which one is currently running?

Comment: The last one is currently running and has been running for several hours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are multiplying thousands of codes by millions of ids, and wondering why you are using up disk space.  You are generating billions of rows.  This will take a long time.

I might make a few suggestions (should you be restarting the process or have resources to run in parallel).

First, save the intermediate results in real tables, perhaps in another database ("myTmp"), so you can monitor progress.

Second, do the aggregation before the join in the final query.  In fact, because you are using temporary tables, put this in a table first:

```
select t1.ID, t1.CODE, count(*) as cnt
from Table1 as t1 
group by t1.ID, t1.CODE;
```

Right now, you are multiplying the original data by including all the additional codes and then grouping.

Then left join from the full table to this one.

An alternative is to having an index on the original table and to try this:

```
insert into Table2(ID,CODE,cnt)
select a.ID, a.CODE,
       (select count(*) from Table1 t1 where a.ID = t1.ID and a.CODE=t1.CODE) as cnt
from temp_ids_codes a
group by a.ID, a.CODE;
```

This may look perverse, but it will use an index on table1 for the correlated subquery.  I'm not a fan of playing such games with SQL, but this could result in the query finishing in our lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

where is `WHERE` clause :

```
create temporary table temp_ids_codes
select ID, CODE
from temp_ids, temp_codes;
```

- table should have PK on collumns`ID, CODE`

Comment: I don't have one...I just want to get the counts for each code on each ID (including zero counts)

Comment: Will my query get faster if I have a PK on those columns?

Comment: Yes, but @Gordon Linoff gave better solution - for his solution, You can add PK as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the following lines (untested query):

```
select a.ID, 
       a.CODE, 
       coalesce(b.countvalue), 0)
from  temp_ids_codes as a
left join ( select count(t1.ID) as countvalue
            from  Table1 as t1
            group by a.ID, a.CODE
           ) b
```

Now your group by will only run on the records that need grouping (and not on all the 0-count records). The right indices could make a huge difference as well.